# How to pick a new color for each plotted line according to a number how close to 1.0 in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

I would like to plot something like the code down below (** see this **). 
So the color is based on a single number of each function. Then I would like to show this in a colormap. Like in the example plot form Matplotlib

```
th = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(3, 3))

ax.plot(th, np.cos(th), **color = 0.98**) # darker color cause close to 1.0
# in the line the color should not change just every line another color!
ax.plot(th, np.sin(th), **color = 0.80**) # lighter color cause not so close to 1.0
```

similar to this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors

N = 50
x = np.arange(N)
# Here are many sets of y to plot vs x
ys = [x + i for i in x]

# We need to set the plot limits, they will not autoscale
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(np.min(x), np.max(x))
ax.set_ylim(np.min(ys), np.max(ys))

line_segments = LineCollection([np.column_stack([x, y]) for y in ys],
                               linewidths=(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2),
                               linestyles='solid')
line_segments.set_array(x)
ax.add_collection(line_segments)
axcb = fig.colorbar(line_segments)
axcb.set_label('Line Number')
ax.set_title('Line Collection with mapped colors')
plt.sci(line_segments)  # This allows interactive changing of the colormap.
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to use the values as array, not `x`. Then take a colormap that has the desired specs (e.g. most colormaps have dark at the start, so you can reverse them by appending `_r` to their name, like `plasma_r`).

Comment: @Steven Did you just copy-paste some tutorial code that is only lightly related? Wouldn't it be easier that you added an image to better explain what you need? (Does it come from https://www.matplotlib.org.cn/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some demo code that probably does what you are asking. The curve_labels and curve_colors are just an illustration of how you could adapt the colorbar for your situation. As mentioned by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in the comments, `plasma_r` might be an attractive color scheme, with the darker colors near to 1.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

th = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128)

curve_labels = ['sin(t)', 'sin(t)/2', 'sin(3*t)', 'sin(4*t)']
curve_colors = [  .98,       .10,       .80,        .40]

cmap = cm.get_cmap('plasma_r')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))

ax.plot(th, np.sin(th), color=cmap(.98))
ax.plot(th, np.sin(th)/2, color=cmap(.10))
ax.plot(th, np.sin(3*th), color=cmap(.80))
ax.plot(th, np.sin(4*th), color=cmap(.40))

ax.set_title('Curves with mapped colors')
cbar = plt.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=None, cmap=cmap), ax=ax, ticks=curve_colors)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(curve_labels)

plt.show()
```

[image: the resulting plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? Or did you need something else?